Bitcoin that I didn't start
-bitcoins


my email address

--how do I block a scam when somehow they're still going through Google form and getting into my email even when I mute them they're still in my Google Gmail account

If you don't recall creating the account it's a scam, criminals are fishing for gullible victims.

Thank u and how do I block them I have tried everything I have report them as a scam and they somehow prove they're not and end up back in my email I have muted them and they still pop back up in my email I don't know what to do with it

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6579?hl=en-GB
